# How to create a OffsetDateTime in java with format 2023-05-05T06:52:27.954Z

Tags: java, date, date-format

I want to generate for example a date now like this format "2023-05-05T06:52:27.954Z"
for with a OffsetDateTime, for calling a method in Java which require a OffsetDateTime
dans the method will generate a request on a server which only accept a format of this pattern "2023-05-05T06:52:27.954Z"
Do you know a mean to do that plz ? The error generated is:

```
expected format Value(Year,4,10,EXCEEDS_PAD)'-'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'-'Value(DayOfMonth,2)'T'Value(HourOfDay,2)':'Value(MinuteOfHour,2)':'Value(SecondOfMinute,2)Fraction(MilliOfSecond,3,3,DecimalPoint)'Z'"<EOL>}"
```

I tried that but nothing to do:

```
String dateStr = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"));
OffsetDateTime maintenant = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"));
```

thank a lot and best regards

Comment: I didn't really understand what you are asking, but probably you don't want `'` around `Z` in the pattern. `Z` means Zulu, meaning the time is in UTC.

Comment: An `OffsetDateTime` cannot have a format. However try `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC) .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)`.

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr the pattern in your `DateTimeFormatter` is wrong

You have…

- an escaped `Z` at the end, which is not in the `String` to be parsed and wich would appear *hard-coded* in every output that is formatted by this very `DateTimeFormatter` instead of the real offset
- no offset or zone in the pattern, which therefore won't produce a `String` with a `Z` for Zulu time / UTC or any other offset

So just replace the `'Z'` by an `X` (and maybe use `uuuu` for the year)…

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    // get "now" in UTC
    OffsetDateTime maintenant = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // print it formatted implicitly (toString)
    System.out.println(maintenant);
    // define a formatter for your desired format
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    // print the OffsetDateTime formatted as desired
    System.out.println(maintenant.format(dtf));
}
```

Output (some seconds ago):

```
2023-10-24T13:56:42.954882Z
2023-10-24T13:56:42.954Z
```

You could create an `OffsetDateTime` from values instead of parsing a `String` or invoking `OffsetDateTime.now()`:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(2023, 5, 5, 6, 52, 27, 954000000, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Having this, you can print it without a formatter or even with the `DateTimeFormatter` defined above, no matter, you will get this:

```
2023-05-05T06:52:27.954Z
```

But that is just one representation of the values the `OffsetDateTime` contains.

Comment: no sorry I need a OffsetDateTime and not a String as a result

Comment: An `OffsetDateTime` has values such as date, time of day and an offset from UTC. **It does not have any format**, that's why there are `DateTimeFormatter`s. Their purpose is to define specific formats and being used for formatting *to* and parsing *from* `String`s.